# Cannot use php artisan command after adding a new command

Tags: laravel

I have a computer where I program and a server where I upload my project automaticly.

I added a command that does a function that uses a function that does some SQL. Since I use that, I cannot use `php artisan` on my computer anymore, but it still works on my server. I already confirmed that it is the custom command because `php artisan` still works after I comment it out. I get this error:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it. (SQL select * from "somewhere where "something" = 0)

Of course the computer where I program hasn't any database running.

I would like to still be able to use `php artisan` on my computer. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you connect to database in a server not in your computer, you must add your IP in cPanel to can connect.